# TypeScript indexed access type constraints behaving strangely

Tags: typescript, generics, type-constraints, discriminated-union

Take this example

```js
interface Person<TName> {
    name: TName;
}

type People =
    | Person<"Levi">
    | Person<"Julien">

type FilteredPersonBase<TPerson extends People> = TPerson["name"] extends "Levi" ? TPerson : never;
type FilteredPerson = FilteredPersonBase<People>; // never

type FilteredPersonBase2<TPerson extends People> = TPerson extends { name: "Levi" } ? TPerson : never;
type FilteredPerson2 = FilteredPersonBase2<People>; // Person<"Levi">
```

I would expect both `FilteredPerson` and `FilteredPerson2` to resolve to `Person<"Levi">`, but they don't. Why does using the indexed access operator in the type constraint resolve differently than using the inline type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the second one should resolve to person `Person<"Levi">`, but lets look at how that happens:

```
FilteredPersonBase2<People>
    // FilteredPersonBase2 is a distributive conditional type since
    // TPerson appears nakedly in the condition of the conditional type
    => FilteredPersonBase2<Person<"Levi">> | FilteredPersonBase2<Person<"Julien">>
    // The conditional type is applied to each member of the union
    => (Person<"Levi"> extends { name: "Levi" } ? Person<"Levi"> : never) |  (Person<"Julien"> extends { name: "Levi" } ? Person<"Julien"> : never)
    // The first application return Person<"Levi">, the second resolves to never
    => Person<"Levi"> | never
    // Never is removed in a union 
    => Person<"Levi">
```

The reason this works is the [distributive behavior of conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

But conditional types only distribute over naked type parameters. In the first example the condition is over `TPerson["name"]` which is not a naked type parameter, so no distribution occurs. Expanding the conditional type we get:

```
FilteredPersonBase<People> =>
    // No distribution 
    People["name"] extends "Levi" ? People : never => 
    // People["name"] just resolves to the union
    "Levi" | "Julien" extends "Levi" ? People : never => 
    // The union does not extend a constituent of the union
    never
```

Since distribution does not occur, `TPerson["name"]` just resolves to `"Levi" | "Julien"` and a union does not extend a constituent. It would be true the other way around (`"Levi" extends TPerson["name"]`) but that would just resolve to the union (`Person`) since a constituent of a union is a sub-type of the union.

Just for fun, you could force distribution over `TPerson` using an always true condition like `TPerson extends TPerson`:

```
type FilteredPersonBase<TPerson extends People> = TPerson extends TPerson ? TPerson["name"] extends "Levi" ? TPerson : never : never;
type FilteredPerson = FilteredPersonBase<People>;  // Person<"Levi">
```